# Update planned order - two committed modifications, only one saved

Tags: updates, abap

I need to update two information on one object: the quantity (PLAF-gsmng) and refresh the planned order via the module function 'MD_SET_ACTION_PLAF'.
I successfully find a way to update each data separately. But when I execute the both solutions the **second modification is not saved on the database**.

Do you know how I can change the quantity & set the action on PLAF (Planned order) table ?

Do you know other module function to update only the quantity ?

Maybe a parameter missing ?

It's like if the second object is locked (sm12 empty, no sy-subrc = locked) ... and the modification is not committed.

I tried to:

- change the order of the algorithm (refresh and after, change PLAF)
- add, remove, move the COMMIT WORK & COMMIT WORK AND WAIT
- add DEQUEUE_ALL or DEQUEUE_EMPLAFE

---

This is the current code:

**1) Read the data**

```
lv_plannedorder = '00000000001'

"Read PLAF data
SELECT SINGLE * FROM PLAF INTO ls_plaf WHERE plnum = lv_plannedorder.
```

**2) Update Quantity data**

```
" Standard configuration for FM MD_PLANNED_ORDER_CHANGE
CLEAR ls_610.
ls_610-nodia = 'X'.     " No dialog display
ls_610-bapco = space.   " BAPI type. Do not use mode 2 -> Action PLAF-MDACC will be autmatically set up to APCH by the FM
ls_610-bapix = 'X'.     " Run BAPI
ls_610-unlox = 'X'.     " Update PLAF

" Customize values
MOVE p_gsmng TO ls_plaf-gsmng. " Change quantity value

MOVE sy-datlo TO ls_plaf-mdacd. " Change by/datetime, because ls_610-bapco <> 2.
MOVE sy-uzeit TO ls_plaf-mdact.

CALL FUNCTION 'MD_PLANNED_ORDER_CHANGE'
  EXPORTING
    ecm61o        = ls_610
    eplaf         = ls_plaf
  EXCEPTIONS
    locked        = 1
    locking_error = 2
    OTHERS        = 3.
" Already committed on the module function
" sy-subrc = 0
```

If I go on the PLAF table, I can see that the quantity is edited. It's working :)

**3) Refresh BOM & change Action (MDACC) and others fields**

```
CLEAR ls_imdcd.
ls_imdcd-pafxl = 'X'.

CALL FUNCTION 'MD_SET_ACTION_PLAF'
  EXPORTING
    iplnum            = lv_plannedorder
    iaccto            = 'BOME'
    iaenkz            = 'X'
    imdcd             = ls_imdcd
  EXCEPTIONS
    illegal_interface = 1
    system_failure    = 2
    error_message     = 3
    OTHERS            = 4.

IF sy-subrc = 0.
  COMMIT WORK.
ENDIF.
```

If I go on the table, no modification (only the modif. of the part 2. can be found on it).

Any idea ?
Maybe because the ls_610-bapco = space ?

Comment: Have You found some "init" modules inside the function pool ? Might be necessary to use them...

Comment: Did you check SM13 while debugging, before and after a commit happens?

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to update planned order quantity with `MD_SET_ACTION_PLAF` too, at least SAP Help [tells us](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_erp60_sp/helpdata/en/9e/e84226c1c311d3b54a0004ac160649/content.htm) so. Why don't you use it like that?

Its call for changing the quantity should *possibly* look like this:

```
DATA: lt_acct LIKE TABLE OF MDACCTO,
      ls_acct LIKE LINE OF lt_acct.

ls_acct-accto = 'BOME'.
APPEND lt_acct.
ls_acct-accto = 'CPOD'.
APPEND lt_acct.

is_mdcd-GSMNG = 'value'             "updated quantity value

CALL FUNCTION 'MD_SET_ACTION_PLAF'
EXPORTING
  iplnum            = iv_plnum
  iaenkz            = 'X'
  IVBKZ             = 'X'
  imdcd             = is_mdcd       "filled with your BOME-related data + new quantity
TABLES
 TMDACCTO           = lt_accto
EXCEPTIONS
  illegal_interface = 1
  system_failure    = 2    
  error_message     = 3.
```

So there is no more need for separate call of `MD_PLANNED_ORDER_CHANGE` anymore and no more problems with update.

I used word *possibly* because I didn't find any example of this FM call in the Web (and SAP docu is quite ambiguous), so I propose this solution just **as is**, without verification.

**P.S.** Possible actions are listed in `T46AS` table, and possible impact of `imdcd` fields on order can be checked in `MDAC` transaction. It is somewhat GUI equivalent of this FM for single order.